# Doctrine getMetadataFactory classes

Tags: annotations, doctrine, entitymanager

I have a question, but I think it is really simple for someone who have knowings about doctrine and its meta-pathes to the entities.

In my annotations is written:

```
  namespace Entity\Model;

  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

    /**
    * TblBaseurls
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_baseurls")
    * @ORM\Entity
    */
    class TblBaseurls
    {
    /**...
```

But this command... 
$classes = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
...let me get an empty array.

If I change the annotations and delete the "@[ORM]\Entity" (means delete only the [ORM]) the classes are found and I get a correctly defined array.

My question about this: What I have to write without to delete all the ORM in the annotations (have to many classes to do that)? I have some changes made in the namespace path, but it takes no effect.

Thanks in advance.

Frank